# Problems with Stripe API

Tags: javascript, express, stripe-payments

I'm working on integrating Stripe payments into my web site, but I'm encountering some issues. Below is the error message and my code structure. I would appreciate any help in understanding and resolving these problems.

**Console errors:**

```
POST http://localhost:3333/create-payment-intent 500 (Internal Server Error)
(anonymous) @ checkout.js:25
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ checkout.js:21
checkout.js:49
Error while fetching client secret:
 IntegrationError:
  Invalid value for stripe.confirmCardPayment intent secret:
   value should be a client_secret string.
  You specified: [object HTMLFormElement].
(anonymous) @ checkout.js:49
Promise.catch (async)
(anonymous) @ checkout.js:48
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ checkout.js:21
```

**Folder Tree:**

```
./server/app.js
./package.json
./website/cup1.jpeg
./website/cup2-removebg-preview.png
./website/checkout.html
./website/style.css
./website/index.html
./website/checkout.js
./.env
./package-lock.json
```

**app.js:**

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const cors = require('cors');

require('dotenv').config();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static('website'));
app.use(cors({
    origin: true
}));
app.use(express.json());

app.get('/checkout.html', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'website', 'checkout.html'));
});

app.post('/create-payment-intent', async (req, res) => {
    const { quantity } = req.body;
    const amount = quantity * 6999;

    try {
        const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
            amount,
            currency: 'eur',
            payment_method_types: ['card'],
        });

        res.json({ client_secret: paymentIntent.client_secret });
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).send({ error: err.message });
    }
});

app.listen(3333, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:3333`);
});
```

**checkout.js:**

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    const stripe = Stripe("pk_test_51O3edCFbwylNhfAiNmsIUvT9Ey6P2QiAOIhgLKZD04uUdZXueGGrt0I6M4loZGNGtirofJq1ODRdLx27z0Ur9vzf00wIs4bjHE");
    const elements = stripe.elements();
    const card = elements.create('card');
    card.mount('#card-element');
    const quantityInput = document.getElementById('quantity');
    const totalAmount = document.getElementById('total-amount');
    const form = document.getElementById('payment-form client-secret');
    const errorDiv = document.getElementById('error');
    quantityInput.addEventListener('input', function () {
        const quantity = quantityInput.value;
        const amount = (69.99 * quantity).toFixed(2);
        totalAmount.textContent = amount + ' EUR';
    });

    form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        stripe.createPaymentMethod({
            type: 'card',
            card: card,
        }).then(function (result) {
            if (result.error) {
                errorDiv.textContent = result.error.message;
            } else {
                fetch('/create-payment-intent', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({ quantity: quantityInput.value }),
                }).then(function (result) {
                    return result.json();
                }).then(function (data) {
                    data.clientSecret = document.getElementById("payment-form client-secret");
                    if (data.clientSecret) {
                        stripe.confirmCardPayment(data.clientSecret, {
                            payment_method: result.paymentMethod.id,
                        }).then(function (result) {
                            if (result.error) {
                                errorDiv.textContent = result.error.message;
                            } else {
                                alert("All good");
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        console.error("Missing client secret from the server.");
                    }
                }).catch(function (error) {
                    console.error("Error while fetching client secret: " + error);
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**package.json:**

```json
{
  "name": "unvaxxed",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "I sell cups",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server/app.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "stripe": "^14.1.0"
  }
}
```

I understand there might be issues with this code, and I would greatly appreciate your assistance in resolving them. My goal is to successfully integrate Stripe payments into my website. Have a good one!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I take it that's where the issue is: `data.clientSecret = document.getElementById("payment-form client-secret")` Not sure what this is for, your `clientSecret` should just be the object in the response to your fetch. Stripe's official docs unpack it like this: ` const { clientSecret } = await response.json();` https://stripe.com/docs/payments/quickstart?lang=node&client=html

Comment: @Lucky2501 Thank you for your precious comment, as the if data.clientSecret is not in an async, i added the line `data.clientSecret = result.client_secret`, but still gives me similar errors 
```\
POST http://localhost:3333/create-payment-intent 500 (Internal Server Error)
(anonymous) @ checkout.js:25
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ checkout.js:21
checkout.js:46 Missing client secret from the server.
(anonymous) @ checkout.js:46
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ checkout.js:33
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ checkout.js:21
```

Comment: yeah you don't need `await` since you have `.then()`, but shouldn't it be `...return result.json()}).then(function (data) { if (data['client_secret']) {...` ?

Comment: @Lucky2501 How should it be? Thank you for your precious support and patience.

Comment: @Lucky2501 nvm i fixed thank you anyway have a good day <3